# Problem listing every file on solution folder in ASP .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to list the names of files (in this case, articles) in an unordered list, but I'm having problems getting the absolute path of files. How can I get a reliable and standard-compliant solution to listing solution filenames in ASP .NET Core?

I have tried calling Directory.EnumerateFiles (With and without the ~ in the directory path parameter)

I also have tried to use GetFiles, getting similar results on the pathing error.

My code is the following:

```
<p>
    <ul>
    @foreach (string articulo in Directory.EnumerateFiles("~/Views/Articulo"))
    {
        <li>
            <a asp-controller="Articulo" asp-action="@articulo">@articulo</a>
        </li>
    }
    </ul>
</p>
```

At the moment, the DOM on the solution is as follows:

```
-Root Application

  -Views
    -Articulo
      -Todo.cshtml //Only page in the folder
```

I would expect some errors trying to come up with correct anchor tags, but instead I get a pathing error:

```
'Directory.EnumerateFiles("~/Views/Articulo")' threw an exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147024893
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Documents\\Source\\Repos\\MyRepo\\MySolution\\~\\Views\\Articulo'."
    Source: "System.IO.FileSystem"
    StackTrace: "   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1.CreateDirectoryHandle(String path, Boolean ignoreNotFound)\r\n   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerator`1..ctor(String directory, EnumerationOptions options)\r\n   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerable`1..ctor(String directory, FindTransform transform, EnumerationOptions options)\r\n   at System.IO.Enumeration.FileSystemEnumerableFactory.UserFiles(String directory, String expression, EnumerationOptions options)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.InternalEnumeratePaths(String path, String searchPattern, SearchTarget searchTarget, EnumerationOptions options)\r\n   at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(String path)"
    TargetSite: {IntPtr CreateDirectoryHandle(System.String, Boolean)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EnumerateFiles("~/Views/Articulo")` won't expand the `~`. You need get the real path manuaylly:

```
@using System.IO
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env

<ul>
@{
    var dir = System.IO.Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath,"Views/Articulo");
}
@if(System.IO.Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    @foreach (string articulo in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir))
    {
        <li>
            <a asp-controller="Articulo" asp-action="@articulo">@articulo</a>
        </li>
    }
}else{
    <span>"No Files"</span>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Would you care to share why are you injecting that interface on line 2? I am kinda new and don't quite know why you included it.

Comment: @abarazac I inject the `IHostingEnvironment` so that I can get the content root by `env.ContentRootPath` without any hard work :)

Comment: Oh, so that way you can combine it later. Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Will try it out later when I'm off work, but I'd say it seems to be the correct answer. Thank you again.

Comment: @abarazac If you have any further question about this thread, feel free to update me :)